# Is the robot Atom self aware?

Tags: real-steel

When they examine the robot in the morning (after the kid dragged it out of the mud) Bailey makes the comment that it is unlike anything she has ever seen before. (The next day she suddenly declares him to be a sparring robot).

When Max is out playing with Atom he has the robot lift him up and he asked the robot if he can understand him. He then tells the robot he will keep his secret.

Later in the movie before a fight Max is working on Atom in the staging room. Max and Charlie are invited to the box office. When they leave Atom is left and he turns and looks at himself in the mirror.

**Was Atom more than just a simple sparring robot?**

Comment: This was a surprisingly good movie, IMHO. Better than I had expected.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We don't know for sure, and it's intentional : here an quote from [Interview: ‘Real Steel’ Director Shawn Levy](http://screenrant.com/real-steel-interview-shawn-levy-steven-spielberg-rothc-134372/)

> SR: The idea of Atom’s sentience is introduced in the film, but is never fully explored, was that a conscious decision?
>
> I had three versions of the movie. One Atom is alive, confirmed, a soulful, sentient being. Two, we confirm that Atom is just a machine regardless of what this boy believes, and three, maybe. Maybe the boy is right, but maybe he isn’t and we will never know and obviously I went with version three. Because when I confirmed or denied Atom’s consciousness the movie lost a certain magic. I think it’s epitomized in the scene where Atom is alone in the locker room and he’s looking at himself in the mirror. Some people think they see him move, and some people don’t.

Comment: The ambiguity is exactly what I loved about the movie. All the characters kept insisting that it is just a machine and all its behavior can be explained through the shadow function. The dialogue says one thing but the scenes are designed to make us feel the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

I have reason to believe so, especially after the scene where max spoke to atom and said; "don't worry, your secret's safe with me." But it seemed more like atom was meant to represent a father figure to max. I started believing in the theory right after the scene where max hides around the corner. the scene occurred round about the 47th minute into the film.

I also found that Zeus seemed like he was also  self-aware. Unfortunately I can't provide any evidence for this statement. a lot of the information needed can be found between the 47-49 minute.

Comment: Zeus did indeed seem self-aware when he glared at Max as he walked past him.

Answer (score 0):

I think that when Max is lifted up by Atom he is projecting what he felt he could not say to his father and we are reading any response or movement from Atom as recognition.

Max has observed his father and his defensiveness/guardedness and talks to atom to relate to his Dad. When he says "your secret is safe with me" to Atom he is vocalising his observations of his father and recognises that his father is in pain and drifting after the loss of Max's mother.

Atom is a medium by which Max and his dad can reach each other and communicate. Max's selection of atom is inspirational and emotional.

The scene in the locker room also promotes the idea that Atom is actually the representation of Max's dad's spirit returning and recovering after the loss of his wife and realising that he has a son who he can start to feel he can love and for whom he can be a father figure for and a role model.

Atom's success is an indication of Max's dad's desire and ability that he can fight for his son. The declaration the father character attempts to make to Max after the Zeus fight is that he never wanted to let Max go, loved Max's mother so much, always loved him, but was hurt and afraid and a failure, and that he is sorry.

So to answer if Atom is self aware: **no he is not**; it is a clever trick by the director to make us project our feelings we have for an estranged father and a son who has lost his mother and need each other to heal each other on to Atom and that makes us believe Atom is sentient.